# (Firefox?) Difference between `console.log( iframe )` + inspecting `contentWindow` vs `console.log( iframe.contentWindow )` - different outputs

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, console.log

Consider a HTML document as follows

```
<div id="foobar"></div>
<iframe id="content" src="https://example.com/someUri"></iframe>
```

Furtheron consider a JavaScript as follows

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function ( event ) {
    var content = document.querySelector( '#content' );
    console.log( content );
    console.log( content.contentWindow );
} );
```

While inspecting the 1st console output of `content` the `contentWindow` property of the element will be shown as a window element based on the same URI as specified in the iFrame's `src` attribute. But the 2nd console output shows a window element based on the URI `about:blank`.

As mentioned in the title I'm using FireFox (59.0.1 x64).

I'm willing to accept that but I like to know why?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this issue is based on the fact that `DOMContentLoaded` does not wait for the iFrame content to be loaded.

In order the output of `contentWindow` is based on a blank page right in the moment the main document has been completely loaded. In fact the output of the iFrame itself would show the same result during the inspection right in the same moment.

**But**

The console updates the output of the iFrame immediately on every change but it doesn't for the single log of the contentWindow property. While the update is so fast one cannot simply recognize the change in the console and could assume an issue in the first place, like I did.

---

**Edit (2018-03-20)**

Meanwhile I found out, that the iFrame first contains a dummy before loading the content passed in `src`.